# How to access Layout in QML in script?

Tags: javascript, qml

I want to access the Layout property in QML script like this:

```
function foobar()
{
  var element = <QML "Text" in "GridLayout">;
  element.Layout.topMargin = 23;
}
```

is this possible?

Comment: Why wouldn't you just assign an `id` field to your GridLayout and then reference it in your code?

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem to do as following:

```
GridLayout {
    anchors.fill: parent
     Text {
         id: txt
         Layout.topMargin: 100
     }
}
...
txt.Layout.topMargin = 10;
```

But I guess the right way is to do that in more declarative way:

```
GridLayout {
    anchors.fill: parent
     Text {
         id: txt
         property int topMargin: 100
         Layout.topMargin: topMargin
     }
}
...
txt.topMargin = 10;
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are asking about whether you can access an Item's attached properties externally / dynamically, then yes.

Example:

```
ColumnLayout {
    Rectangle {
        Layout.fillHeight: true
        Layout.fillWidth: true
    }
    Rectangle {
        id: bottomRect
    }
}
MouseArea {
    onClicked: {
        bottomRect.Layout.fillHeight = true;
    }
}
```

If you are talking about accessing an element using the

```
< "< element type >" in "< parent element type >" >
```

syntax, then no.  That fails to interpret.